# why the algebra $A = k[x]/(x^n)$ has finite representation type?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, modules, representation-theory

Suppose that $k$ is algebraically closed. Then why the algebra $A = k[x]/(x^n)$ has finite representation type? please clarify the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome! In general, please provide context to your question and let us know what you have already tried.

*Hint to the exercise:* A module over $A$ is the same as a $k$-vector space $V$ together with a $k$-linear endomorphism $f: V\to A$ such that $f^n=0$. Now apply what you know about normal forms of nilpotent endomorphisms of finite-dimensional vector spaces.